# Why does electrical resistivity have units of $\Omega \cdot \mathrm{m}$ rather than $\Omega \cdot \mathrm{m}^3 ?$

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, definition, units, dimensional-analysis

[Electrical resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) has units of $\Omega \cdot \mathrm{m} .$  However, since resistivity can be described as the resistance of a unit cube, shouldn't the units therefore be $\Omega \cdot \mathrm{m}^3$ instead?

I ask after seeing this question to which the answer is apparently $\left(\text{D}\right) :$

> $
> \text{Resistivity can be described correctly as:} \\
> \hspace{1em}
> \begin{array}{cl}
> \mathbf{A} & \text{resistance of a unit length.} \\
> \mathbf{B} & \text{resistance per unit area.}   \\
> \mathbf{C} & \text{resistance per unit volume.} \\
> \mathbf{D} & \text{resistance of a unit cube.}
> \end{array}
> $

Comment: "resistivity is defined as resistance of a unit cube": **Absolutely not**

Comment: Sorry I meant described as rather than defined as

Comment: @Massimo Why "absolutely not"?

Comment: @my2cts Because the equality of two numerical values does not imply the equality of two corresponding quantities. Never confuse numerical values with quantities.

Comment: I like how they included both "_resistance of a unit volume_" and "_resistance of a unit cube_" as possible answers.

Comment: @Nat That was a transcription error that you made.  The real question read resistance _per unit volume_, which does have different connotations.  A resistance _per unit volume_ would be units of Ohms per litre for example,  whereas resistance _of a unit cube_ could still work out to being expressed as resistance per unit length, even though it measures a resistance of a unit cube (as we see here).

Comment: @JMac I appreciate you fixing the transcription error!  That said, my comment was about how they had both $\left( \text{C} \right)$ and $\left( \text{D} \right) .$ 
 I just like how they included both "_volume_" and "_cube_" since a simple dimensional analysis wouldn't be sufficient to distinguish between them.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano  Well ... I think **D** is correct.  The unit cube must be unit in the system of unit used.  Typically that means a cube 1 cm x 1 cm X 1 cm.   Nonetheless, the question in question is a terrible question, and none of the answers are particularly good.  Concerning your objection to values vs quantities, we do this all the time.  Velocity is defined as the displacement of an object in a unit time.   Velocity defined as displacement.  Different quantities, identical values.

Comment: @Massimo Which "numerical value" do you mean? There are only physical quantities here. To measure resistivity I would not recommend a cube, though. A more elongated shape gives better results.

Comment: I like the description here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility. It seems to be something like newton per (coulomb times speed times carrier density) if my mental arithmetic checks out...

Comment: @my2cts, depends entirely what kind of material. If it's copper, you want a very long narrow shape. If it's polyester you want a very short, fat shape.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Do you have reference wherein the resistivity of polyester is determined? I would expect quite a zoo of exotic effects contrubuting to it. Hopping, defects, tunneling, humidity entering t he spaghetti structure. Not exactly your standard conductor.

Comment: @my2cts, I only meant you probably want to get your sample resistance to be somewhere between 10 milliohms and 100 megohms if you can manage it. The geometry needed for metals will be different than for insulators.

Comment: @ThePhoton Good point.

Comment: Resistivity is not dependent on volume instead it is dependent on ratio of length and average area of cross section

Answer (score 4):

The resistance $R$ of a body grows with bigger length $l$
(a longer wire has greater resistance)
and **shrinks** with bigger cross-section area $A$ (a thicker wire has smaller resistance).
Hence you have
$$ R = \rho\frac{l}{A}$$
and resistivity $\rho$ must have unit $\Omega\cdot$m.

Comment: How does this equation link to the answer which is D (resistance of a unit cube).

Comment: @daniel For a cube you have $A = l^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Resitivity can be thought of as resistance of a unit cube, but for a unit cube, the resistance doesn't work out to $\text{material constant} * \text{volume}$.

Instead, restivity ($\rho$) is given by $\rho = \frac {RA}{L}$ (where $R$ is resistance, $A$ is area and $L$ is length of material) or to rearrange in terms of net resistance $R = \frac {\rho L}{A}$.

We can see that this suggests that resistance will *increase* with length, but *decrease* with area.  This should make sense, because if you send the same current through a wider area, it should experience less resistance, and if you push the same current through a longer path of resistance, it should experience more net resistance over the path.

You can see from that relationship that the units will work out to resistance per unit length, not per unit volume.

Comment: "Resitivity is defined as resistance of a unit cube": **NO**

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You're right, I was just using their terminology.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano  **YES**.  The unit cube must be unit in the system of unit used.  Typically that means a cube 1 cm x 1 cm X 1 cm.   Nonetheless, the question in question is a terrible question, and none of the answers are particularly good.

Comment: @garyp As several others around here, you confuse numerical values and physical quantities. It's sad to see physicists make this mistake, but I don't have enough time to fight against this wrong belief.